# Unity3d Webplayer hideFlashCallback

Tags: javascript, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have a game running inside Facebook and I'm trying to hide the game window when a user clicks on their search bar, friends, notifications or messages. I've looked into Facebook's Javascript API and they have this "hideFlashCallback" delegate you can set in FB.init(). However it doesn't seem like the callback is being hit. The alert(state) doesn't get called.

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo $config->app_id; ?>',
      channelUrl : '<?php echo $config->app_host; ?>/channel.html',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      frictionlessRequests : true,
      hideFlashCallback : function(params) {
          var state = params.state;
          alert(state);
          }
      });
     };

     (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <center>
        <div id="unityPlayer">
           <div class="missing">
             <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
              <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
             </a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I added a dummy object right about my unityPlayer div and it seems to work now.

```
<object width="1" height="1" id="facebookFakeFlash" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></object>
```